# rxjava : be notified when multiple observables have completed

Tags: android, system.reactive, retrofit

I'm using rxjava together with retrofit on Android.
I have several retrofit observables that are started together and that all run in different threads.

I'd like to be notified (via callback) when all of them have completed.

I've looked into various Observable 'combine' functions on the documentation but couldn't find one that does this exact thing.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Bye,
Marco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more digging I think what I was looking for is:

http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html

or

http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/combinelatest.html

It seems to me that when the Observables will emit only one item (i.e. they could bi Single) zip & combinelatest behave similarly.